# Fire + Smoke bake shows steps (still not solved)

Tags: baking, smoke-simulation, fire

When I bake my fire and smoke on a moving object (character), I get these unrealistic 'steps' in the bake (you can see the arm is rendered every frame apart, instead of a continuous natural fire). Does anyone know how to fix this or set it up?
[image]

[image: object settings]

If I increase the 'sampling substep' it still doesn't feel natural.

[image]

[image]

Is there another solution to make this fire on a fast moving object more realistic?

Here are my domain settings, just in case;

[image]
[image]

Comment: How many _Sampling Substeps_ have you set on the _Flow_ object? Would you mind sharing at least screenshots of the basic _Domain_ and _Flow_ object settings so that we do not have to blindly guess what might be wrong?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks! As you suggested I increased the Sampling Substeps to '5', which gives a slightly better result (as I uploaded the result above), but still there's seems to be a clear problem of 'substeps' in the animation that seem odd and far from natural fire simulation. I also added the domain settings.

Comment: Well, for moving objects I usually set the substeps to something like 20. The _Timesteps Maximum_ and _Minimum_ in the domain's _Use Adaptive Time Steps_ settings could also help calculating the smoke more accurate, I sometimes set it to 6 and 2, but it also increases baking time by quite a bit.

Comment: Wow, 20 sounds like a big difference. I'm going to try setting those substeps and timesteps. Let it bake for a while. ;-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ahum. Sorry. I'm back again. Sampling Substep set on 20. Timestep Max to 6 and mind at 2. Even decreased the CFL number to 1. Still get the 'gaps' in the bake result. See example. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ccpc4k3rl39kyjp/Schermafbeelding%202023-04-21%20om%2014.41.19.png?dl=0) Any other ideas?